# Mediaplayer en servicio para app de Radio Streaming

Tags: android, android-studio

Hice una app para una radio online de un pueblo, me gustaría saber si me pueden ayudar para que se reproduzca en segundo plano en un servicio, para que cuento se mate la actividad principal la radio se siga escuchando.

Les comparto código:

```
package ar.com.asset.www.radiostream;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnplay;
Button btnstop;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

boolean prepared = false;
boolean started = false;

String stream = "http://radioscoop.hu:80/live.mp3";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnplay);
    btnstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstop);
    btnplay.setEnabled(false);
    btnplay.setText("CARGANDO");
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    new PlayerTask().execute(stream);

    btnplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (started) {
                started = false;
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                btnplay.setText("Play");
            } else {
                started = true;
                prepared = true;
                mediaPlayer.start();
                btnplay.setText("Pause");
            }
        }
    });

    btnstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            started = false;
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            btnplay.setText("Play");

            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                prepared = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    });
}


class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        btnplay.setEnabled(true);
        btnplay.setText("PLAY");
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

}

Comment: Recomiendo como opción la pantalla se mantenga visible con esto se reproducirá sin interrupción.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando traté de realizar esto me encontré el problema de realizar la reproducción en segundo plano, además Google Playstore por politica no permite reproducción en segundo plano, como opción es mantener siempre visible la pantalla, lo cual permite la reproducción sin problema:

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```